# dash core dropdown callback update problem

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created 2 dropdowns. both of them fires on single button. 4 days back this layout was working great.
But since few days back only one callback is firing and not other one.
I tried to look into the callback which was not firing. It turns out the callback firing but it is not returning anything.
I tried to print everything till return of the same callback. everything prints well.
Are there any changes has been made in core components?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output,State

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('get attributes',id='get_attributes',n_clicks=0),    
    dcc.Dropdown(id="select_dep_var"),
    html.Div(id = 'store_dep_var'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id="drp1"),
    dcc.Dropdown(id="drp2"),        
   ])


@app.callback(Output('drp1','options'),
          [Input('get_attributes','n_clicks'),
           Input('select_dep_var','children')])
def drp1update(n_click,depend_var):
    if n_click > 0:
        if depend_var is not None:
            return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in data[depend_var].unique()]


@app.callback(Output('drp2','options'),
          [Input('get_attributes','n_clicks'),
           Input('select_dep_var','children')])
def drp2update(n_click,depend_var):
    if n_click > 0:
        if depend_var is not None:
            return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in data[depend_var].unique()]


@app.callback(Output('store_dep_var','children'),
              [Input('select_dep_var','value')])
def store_dep_var(dep_var):
    return dep_var


@app.callback(Output('select_dep_var','options'),
              [Input('get_attributes','n_clicks')])
def select_dep_var(click):
    if click >0:
        print('returning attributes in dropdown')
        print(click)
        print(data.columns)
        return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in data.columns]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like two of your callbacks are taking the wrong input, `drp1update` and `drp2update`. They are taking `children` from `select_dep_var` but they should be taking `value`, I think.

```py
@app.callback(Output('drp1','options'),
          [Input('get_attributes','n_clicks'),
           Input('select_dep_var','value')])
def drp1update(n_click,depend_var):
    if n_click > 0:
        if depend_var is not None:
            return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in data[depend_var].unique()]


@app.callback(Output('drp2','options'),
          [Input('get_attributes','n_clicks'),
           Input('select_dep_var','value')])
def drp2update(n_click,depend_var):
    if n_click > 0:
        if depend_var is not None:
            return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in data[depend_var].unique()]
```

When I made that change, the callbacks worked and updated the values in the other two dropdowns. I just used a dummy dataframe. You can probably also drop the `n_clicks` input from both of those callbacks, because the value from the dropdown will be enough to fire them.